# how do I set missing values using PmmlTransformation in r

Tags: r, pmml

I have a dataframe in r which has some NA values in it. How can I use pmmlTransformations to set a missing value treatment for these fields. Ive seen that you can set missingValue treatments when transforming the data (normalization, field mapping, etc) but I would like to know how to just set the missing values with out having to normalize the data.

```
    library(pmml)
    library(pmmlTransformations)

    df <- data.frame(id=1:5, y=1:5, x=c(2,4,3,NA,8))
    dataBox <- WrapData(df)

    # update the wrapped data to set x=1 when it its NA

    fit <- glm(formula=y~x, data = dataBox$data)

    pmml(fit, transforms=dataBox)
```

Many thanks in advance

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add the `missingValueReplacement=1` attribute to all `MiningField` elements in the PMML document, then append `unknownValue = 1` to your `pmml::pmml.glm` function call:

```
library(pmml)
df <- data.frame(id=1:5, y=1:5, x=c(2,4,3,NA,8))
# Set missing values to 1 before training a GLM model
df$x[is.na(df$x)] = 1
fit <- glm(formula=y~x, data = df)
# Encode information about the missing value transformation into the PMML document
pmml = pmml.glm(fit, unknownValue = 1)
saveXML(pmml, "glm.pmml")
```

Sure, the `unknownValue` parameter appears to be deprecated, but it does exactly what you need without firing up a complex sequence of transformations.

Comment: I've check the pmml which was produced, and it appears that missingValueReplacement="1" for both x and y, which is not quite what I wanted to achieve.

I can imagine there will be a time when I have multiple fields which I need to set missing values for. Therefore it would be best if I could set them to different values.

Comment: If you check the source code of `pmml::.pmmlMiningSchema` function, then it is easy to see that you can pass a `data.frame` instead of a scalar value for the `unknownValue` parameter. This way every field can have its own missingValueReplacement value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unknownValue parameter:
`pmml.glm(glm, transforms = dataBox, unknownValue = 0)`
but this will be applied to all you variables, including your target variable.

I wrote a fix that allows specifying replacement values for each of the variables: 
https://github.com/guleatoma/pmml

Using this version of the package you can do this:

`pmml.glm(glm, transforms = dataBox, unknownValue = list("x1" = 0, "x2" = 100))`